# how to reloaddata of a collection view from a different file?

Tags: swift, reloaddata

i have two collection views and i have two swift files for each one. how do i reload data from one collection view file to the the other?  they are both contained within one view controller i have tried .......................................................................................................................................................

```
let cell1: collectionview1 = collectionview1(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    cell1.collview1.reloadData()
```

it returns nil though,

collview1 is an outlet of collectview
@IBOutlet var collview1: UICollectionView!
......................................................................................................................................................